# Proving a matrix-related theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been asked to provide the proof for the following theorem:
$$"\text{Let }\mathbb{A}\text{ be a 2x2 non-diagonalisable matrix with constant real entries, (i.e.: It has only one}\\\text{ linearly independent eigenvector }u\text{ corresponding to the repeated eigenvalue } \lambda).\\\text{Then the general solution to the system }v'(t)=\mathbb{A}v(t)\text{ is given by:}\\v(t)=e^{\lambda t}v_{0}+te^{\lambda t}(\mathbb{A}-\lambda \mathbb{I}_{2})v_{0}"$$

And I'm given the hint that $(\mathbb{A}-\lambda \mathbb{I}_{2})(\mathbb{A}-\lambda \mathbb{I}_{2})=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ can be used to sho $(\mathbb{A}-\lambda \mathbb{I}_{2})v_{0}$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbb{A}$.

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: I don't even really know where to begin, if I'm honest. I'm just reviewing past exam papers to prepare for an exam and this was one of the final questions.

Comment: The hint invites you to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $(A - \lambda I_2)^2 = 0$, verify that $\lambda(A - \lambda I_2) = A(A - \lambda I_2)$. If you like, this tells us that $\lambda(A - \lambda I_2)v_0 = A(A - \lambda I_2)v_0$, which is to say that $(A - \lambda I_2)v_0$ is indeed an eiegnvector.

With that established, take the derivative of the given expression for $v(t)$ and simplify as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\left[e^{\lambda t}v_{0}+te^{\lambda t}(A-\lambda I_{2})v_{0}\right]' &= [e^{\lambda t}]' v_0 + [te^{\lambda t}]'(A - \lambda I_2)v_0\\
&= \lambda e^{\lambda t} v_0 + (\lambda t + 1)e^{\lambda t} (A - \lambda I_2) v_0
\\ & = 
\lambda e^{\lambda t} v_0 + e^{\lambda t} (A - \lambda I_2) v_0
+ \lambda t e^{\lambda t} (A - \lambda I_2) v_0
\\ & = 
\lambda e^{\lambda t} v_0 + e^{\lambda t} A v_0
- \lambda e^{\lambda t} v_0
+  t e^{\lambda t} \cdot \lambda(A - \lambda I_2) v_0
\\ & = 
e^{\lambda t} A v_0
+  t e^{\lambda t} \cdot \lambda(A - \lambda I_2) v_0
\\ & = 
e^{\lambda t} A v_0
+  t e^{\lambda t} \cdot A(A - \lambda I_2) v_0
\\ & =
A[e^{\lambda t}v_{0}+te^{\lambda t}(A-\lambda I_{2})v_{0}] = Av(t).
\end{align}
$$
So indeed, $v(t)$ satisfies $v'(t) = Av(t)$.